# Which is faster trigger or stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a trigger on each table that handles a history log. The trigger is the exact same on every table. See below.

If I move this to a stored procedure, will it be faster?

Also if I use a stored procedure will the trigger release for the user to continue?

```
create trigger ' + @TABLE_NAME + '_ChangeTracking on ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' for 
insert, update, delete
as
    declare @bit int ,
            @field int ,
            @maxfield int ,
            @char int ,
            @fieldname varchar(128) ,
            @TableName varchar(128) ,
            @PKCols varchar(1000) ,
            @sql nvarchar(max), 
            @Type nvarchar(1) ,
            @PKValueSelect varchar(1000),
            @MasterId nvarchar(max) = ''0''

    select @TableName = ''' + @TABLE_NAME + '''

    if exists(select * from CNF_HIL_Tables where referencetable = @TableName and Active = 1)
    begin
        if exists (select * from inserted)
            if exists (select * from deleted)
                select @Type = ''2''
            else
                select @Type = ''3''
        else
            select @Type = ''1''

        select * into #ins from inserted
        select * into #del from deleted

        select @PKCols = coalesce(@PKCols + '' and'', '' on'') + '' i.'' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '' = d.'' + c.COLUMN_NAME
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk 
        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c on c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME and c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
        where pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
          and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ''PRIMARY KEY''

        select @PKValueSelect = coalesce(@PKValueSelect+''+'','''') + ''convert(varchar(100), coalesce(i.'' + COLUMN_NAME + '',d.'' + COLUMN_NAME + ''))''
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk    
        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c on c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME and c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME  
        where pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName   
          and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ''PRIMARY KEY'' 

        select @field = 0, 
               @maxfield = max(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        where TABLE_NAME = @TableName

        while @field < @maxfield
        begin
            select @field = min(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
            from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            where TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
              and ORDINAL_POSITION > @field

            select @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
            select @bit = power(2,@bit - 1)
            select @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1

            if substring(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0 or @Type in (''1'',''3'')
        begin
            select @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ORDINAL_POSITION = @field

            if exists(select * from CNF_Hil_Columns INNER JOIN CNF_HIL_Tables    ON CNF_HIL_Tables.TablesId = CNF_Hil_Columns.TablesId
                                where CNF_HIL_Tables.referencetable = @TableName  and CNF_Hil_Columns.ColumnName = @fieldname
                                    and CNF_Hil_Columns.Active = 1
                        )
            begin

                if @MasterId = 0
                begin
                    select @sql = ''insert DATA_HIL_Master (OperationType, ReferenceTable, ReferenceId, UserId, WorkstationId, InsDateTime)''
                    select @sql = @sql + '' select '''''' + @Type + ''''''''                                                
                    select @sql = @sql + '', '''''' + @TableName + ''''''''     
                    select @sql = @sql + '','' + @PKValueSelect     
                    select @sql = @sql + '',convert(varchar(1000),i.Last_UserId_Log)''
                    select @sql = @sql + '',convert(varchar(1000),i.Last_WorkstationId_Log)''
                    select @sql = @sql + '',convert(varchar(1000),i.Last_DateTime_Log)''
                    select @sql = @sql + '' from #ins i full outer join #del d''
                    select @sql = @sql + @PKCols 
                    select @sql = @sql + '' SELECT @MasterId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() ''
                    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N''@MasterId nvarchar(max) OUTPUT'', @MasterId OUTPUT
                end

                select @sql = ''insert data_HIL_Detail (MasterId, ColumnName, OriginalValue, ModifiedValue)''
                select @sql = @sql + '' select convert(varchar(1000),'' + @MasterId + '')''
                select @sql = @sql + '','''''' + @fieldname + ''''''''
                select @sql = @sql + '', convert(varchar(1000),d.'' + @fieldname + '')''
                select @sql = @sql + '', convert(varchar(1000),i.'' + @fieldname + '')''
                select @sql = @sql + '' from #ins i full outer join #del d''
                select @sql = @sql + @PKCols

                EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
            END
        END
    END 
END
```

Comment: Its a moot point, unless you do something quite complicated, you don't have access to the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables in a stored procedure. The real question is, what problem are you trying to solve that has you ask in the first place?

Comment: Holy crap, that stuff is a trigger? That's sort of insane. If you're asking "should i remove this trigger and transition the logic to a stored procedure" the answer is almost certainly yes unless there is some compelling reason to keep it as a trigger.

Comment: That is rather a convoluted trigger, and will probably trash performance in some circumstances (depends on your use of these business objects of course). Perhaps you should explore existing technologies, like change data capture and change tracking (see [Track Data Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server)) to see if they suit your business requirements and are practical enough for your needs.

Comment: SQL Server supports change tracking in various ways, all of them outperform triggers. And in any case, triggers and stored procedures are different tools designed to perform different tasks. You're comparing apples with oranges.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually searching for an answer to this question and stumbled in here.

I've found a lot of different answers, but as a student, I am currently being told that "stored procedures run quicker than individual SQL statements; this improves performance." So, it seems the answer is "yes".

However, it seems "performance" may be interpreted differently by different people. I'm not very experienced yet, so I don't really understand all the nuances yet. I've seen some comments attributing the difference to "cache", and others that suggest using stored procedure only because of better "control" for security and maintenance rather than anything performance related.

While reading my course material, I also came across something that might be relevant. This is from *Beginning Databases with PostgreSQL: From Novice to Professional* (Stones and Matthew, 2005):

> Stored Procedures reside on the server side, not on the client side, adding to
> access control. Invoked from the client side, only the results are passed on to the caller, this reduces network traffic. Several applications can use a single stored procedure, standardizing processing rules.

So, maybe that's what is meant by "performance".

Stored procedures also seem more similar to functions themselves, which are objects stored in a database and used by all other database objects. Whereas triggers are object associated with a table that runs a function.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Irrespective of trigger or stored procedure, you have got the same code. In trigger, you can not call it directly and in stored procedure, you are calling directly. So, whether you use trigger or stored procedure, execution wise it is same. The first time it is called, the execution plan is cached.

In your case, as you are using specifically using inserted, deleted tables, you should have different stored procedure code to implement auditing. Or you can consider using [SQL Server temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables) or [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server) or [SQL Server auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine)

But, there are few disadvantages of using trigger.

- It can make the transaction longer
- Difficult to debug

Comment: @TT., updated my answer. sorry. I should have looked into the code in detail